# R: How to calculate percentage of each unique value in multiple groups under conditions in other columns?

Tags: r

I have a df, each row represents one game played between two players. I want to calculate each unique civ's winrate in each unique rank group. But My biggest issue is that p1.rank.group and p2.rank.group can be different for one game(row)

So EX: in row 1, civ.won == 'rus', find that p2.civ == 'rus', meaning p2 won, now see that p2.rank.group is 'platinum', record that as 1 win for 'rus' in 'platinum' and record p1.civ == 'english' as 1 loss for 'english' in p1.rank.group = 'diamond'.

Every row should have 1 civ win and 1 civ loss, but those civs have to also be grouped in their respective rank categories to calculate winrate.

I tried:

```
df_p1 = subset(df,select = c(p1.civ,p1.rank.group)) %>%
  group_by(p1.rank.group) %>%
  mutate(civ_count = n_distinct(p1.civ))

df_p2 = subset(df,select = c(p2.civ,p2.rank.group)) %>%
  group_by(p2.rank.group) %>%
  mutate(civ_count = n_distinct(p2.civ))
```

I know how many times each unique civ shows up in each rank group for each player separately, stuck after this

Here is a head(10) version of my df

```
$p1.civ
 [1] "english"           "english"           "french"            "rus"              
 [5] "english"           "french"            "mongols"           "holy_roman_empire"
 [9] "abbasid_dynasty"   "abbasid_dynasty"  

$p1.rank.group
 [1] "diamond"   "silver"    "gold"      "gold"      "platinum"  "conqueror" "gold"     
 [8] "platinum"  "conqueror" "platinum" 

$p2.civ
 [1] "rus"               "holy_roman_empire" "rus"               "mongols"          
 [5] "holy_roman_empire" "english"           "english"           "chinese"          
 [9] "english"           "mongols"          

$p2.rank.group
 [1] "platinum"  "platinum"  "gold"      "platinum"  "platinum"  "conqueror" "platinum" 
 [8] "platinum"  "conqueror" "platinum" 

$civ.won
 [1] "rus"               "holy_roman_empire" "rus"               "mongols"          
 [5] "english"           "english"           "english"           "chinese"          
 [9] "english"           "mongols"
```

```
             p1.civ       p1.rank.group       p2.civ    p2.rank.group         civ.won
1            english       diamond               rus      platinum               rus
2            english        silver holy_roman_empire      platinum holy_roman_empire
3             french          gold               rus          gold               rus
4                rus          gold           mongols      platinum           mongols
5            english      platinum holy_roman_empire      platinum           english
6             french     conqueror           english     conqueror           english
7            mongols          gold           english      platinum           english
8  holy_roman_empire      platinum           chinese      platinum           chinese
9    abbasid_dynasty     conqueror           english     conqueror           english
10   abbasid_dynasty      platinum           mongols      platinum           mongols
```

desired output:

```
rank_group        civilization       winrate    
silver            english             o%
gold              french              o%
                  rus                 50%
                  mongols             0% 
platinum          english             50%
                  holy_roman_empire   33.33%
                  abbasid_dynasty     0%
                  rus                 100%
                  mongols             100%
                  chinese             100%
diamond           english             0%
conqueror         french              0%
                  abbasid_dynasty     0%
                  english             100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your data in long format:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  pivot_longer(matches("^p\\d"),
               names_pattern = "(p\\d).(.*)", names_to = c("player", ".value")) |>
  summarize(winrate = mean(civ == civ.won), .by = c(rank.group, civ)) |>
  arrange(desc(rank.group))
```

Note: I created a "player" column with the pivot function in case that is useful for you for other calculations (it gets removed by this pipeline anyway). However, you can simply replace `"player"` with `NA` to delete it entirely.

---

**Output**

```
  rank.group civ               winrate
   <chr>      <chr>               <dbl>
 1 silver     english             0    
 2 platinum   rus                 1    
 3 platinum   holy_roman_empire   0.333
 4 platinum   mongols             1    
 5 platinum   english             1    
 6 platinum   chinese             1    
 7 platinum   abbasid_dynasty     0    
 8 gold       french              0    
 9 gold       rus                 0.5  
10 gold       mongols             0    
11 diamond    english             0    
12 conqueror  french              0    
13 conqueror  english             1    
14 conqueror  abbasid_dynasty     0
```

**Data**

```r
structure(list(p1.civ = c("english", "english", "french", "rus", 
"english", "french", "mongols", "holy_roman_empire", "abbasid_dynasty", 
"abbasid_dynasty"), p1.rank.group = c("diamond", "silver", "gold", 
"gold", "platinum", "conqueror", "gold", "platinum", "conqueror", 
"platinum"), p2.civ = c("rus", "holy_roman_empire", "rus", "mongols", 
"holy_roman_empire", "english", "english", "chinese", "english", 
"mongols"), p2.rank.group = c("platinum", "platinum", "gold", 
"platinum", "platinum", "conqueror", "platinum", "platinum", 
"conqueror", "platinum"), civ.won = c("rus", "holy_roman_empire", 
"rus", "mongols", "english", "english", "english", "chinese", 
"english", "mongols")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```